# The set of collaboratively compact operators is compact in $B(X, Y)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm wondering if the set of collaboratively compact operators is compact in $B(X, Y)$?

> A family of bounded operators $\mathscr{A} = \{A: X\to Y\}$ of linear operators, where $X,Y$ are banach spaces are called
>   collectively compact, if for each bounded set $U \subset X$, the image set
>   $\mathscr{A}(U) = \{ Af: f\in U, A \in \mathscr{A}\}$ is relatively compact in $Y$.

But in the Banach space $B(X,Y)$, does $\mathscr{A}$ necessarily form a compact set?

Comment: 4 questions within these last 8 hours ! Take time to breath !

Comment: @JeanMarie Can't breathe without math!

Comment: Nice answer ! I appreciate your humor...